# I'm getting error "Invalid column name"

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.vijay.Transfee" table="TRXN_FEE_TABLE">
<meta attribute="class-description">
This class contains the course details.
</meta>
<id name="Tcode" type="string" column="TRXN_FEE_CODE" >
    </id>
<property name="Icode" type="string" column ="INSTCODE" />
<property name="Pcode" type="string" column ="PRODUCT_CODE" />
<property name="Tcode1" type="string" column ="TRANSACTION_CODE" />
<property name="rebate_code1" type="string" column="REBATE_CODE"/>
</class>
<sql-query name="F_SP" callable="true">
    <return alias="fee"  class="com.vijay.Transfee">
        <return-property name="rebate_code1" column="REBATE_CODE"/>
    </return>
    { call Feeproc1(?) }
 </sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

---

```
package com.vijay;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import java.util.*;

public class A {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        SessionFactory factory = config.configure().buildSessionFactory();
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>1");
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Query query = (Query)session.getNamedQuery("F_SP"); 
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>2");
        List result = query.list();
        System.out.println(query.list());
        Iterator it=result.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            Object[] sublist1 = (Object[])it.next();
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>3");
            String Trx = (String)sublist1[0];
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>4");
            System.out.println(Trx);
        }
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>5");
        System.out.println(result);
}
}
```

I am calling the stored procedure and just printing the one i called but it shows the following error

```
    
    Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
        at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
        at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2536)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
        at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:316)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1842)
        at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:165)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:157)
        at com.vijay.A.main(A.java:24)
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:113)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:147)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:209)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3325)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.findColumn(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1926)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:1515)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:61)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:254)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:250)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:230)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:331)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:668)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:606)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
        ... 7 more
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE LYCAMONEY.Feeproc1(p_cursor  OUT  sys_refcursor)
as rebate_code1 varchar2(20);
begin

  rebate_code1 := null;
  open p_cursor for
    select REBATE_CODE into rebate_code1  from TRXN_FEE_TABLE;

 dbms_output.put_line(rebate_code1 );

end;
/
```

Can any one help me out with this issue...... and also post the correct methodology if

Answer (score 1):

Well, your stored procedure is wrong for starters.  It should be:

```
open p_cursor for
    select REBATE_CODE from TRXN_FEE_TABLE;
```

It's wrong because ref cursor is a pointer to a query.  It doesn't actually fetch any data.

But I don't think that is what is giving you the error.

Comment: thanks for the reply:) I got rid of the Error

Comment: Does that mean your question is answered?

Comment: No it was a silly mistake actually...... i found it later..... i have another question is there any other way to call procedure other than named query...... if session object is the only solution other than named query then no need for hibernate right!!!!! we can just create a simple java class.........

Comment: @vijayakumar - ask this as new question.  SO is a Q&A site not a forum, so it matters that the threads address the original question and nothing else.